# PhpStrom automatic classes creation with alt+enter?

Tags: ide, tdd, phpstorm

I'm new to PHPStorm but I have IDEA for Java.

For TDD, is there a way to create undefined classes with alt+enter, when they don't exist ?
Like you do with methods in phpstorm.

Same thing with interfaces, or interface implementation, and so on...

In general, is there a way to have a quick workflow like in IDEA java ?

Otherwise, is eclipse better ?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made a macro, when my cursor is on the name of the undefined class

- ctrl+w : select all name
- ctrl+c : copy
- alt+Home : go to navigation bar (current namespace)
- alt+insert : new
- type "cl" : filter class
- enter
- ctrl+v : paste the name of the class

Apply only in current package

Answer (score 0):

Quick Fix (a.k.a. <kbd>Alt + Enter</kbd>) does not support creation of missing classes this way yet.

http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-6148 -- subscribe to the ticket (star/vote/comment) to get notified on progress.